# Return 404 page when i check on Docter link checker ,

Tags: wordpress, plugins

i have  url like this

http://localhost/wordpress/story

story is directoy url this is  dynamic url

http://localhost/wordpress/story/post-slug

when i check post-slug  url  with directory url  it's  show 404 status

may i have  issue in rewrite  ?

```
function custom_rewrite_rules() {

    $directory_url = get_option('story_maker_directory');

    // Construct the dynamic rewrite rule using the stored directory URL

    $rewrite_rule = '^' . $directory_url . '/([^/]+)/?$';

    // Add the custom rewrite rule with a higher priority

    add_rewrite_rule($rewrite_rule, 'index.php?custom_post_type=$matches[1]', 'top');
}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rules', 10);

// Add the custom query variable for your custom post type
function custom_query_vars($query_vars) {

    $query_vars[] = 'custom_post_type'; 

    return $query_vars;
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'custom_query_vars');

// Check for custom post type in display_custom_page_content function
function display_custom_page_content() {

    if (get_query_var('custom_post_type')) {

        // Output your custom HTML content here for your custom post type

        include_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'relatedpost.php');

        status_header(200);

        exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'display_custom_page_content');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your '**custom_rewrite_rules function**', ensure that the rewrite rule you construct matches the structure of your URLs accurately.

Double-check that the '**add_rewrite_rule**' function call and the regular expression for the rewrite rule are correctly capturing the '**post-slug**'.

Additionally, ensure that your '**custom_query_vars**' function properly adds the custom query variable. Debugging with '**var_dump**' or '**print_r**' at various points in your code can help you identify where the issue lies and what values are being passed.

Also, confirm that the relatedpost.php file and its contents are correctly included.